# Scale image using input type range with react

Tags: reactjs, image, input, range, scale

I wish I could change the scale of my image with a range with React, but I don't know how to do it.

Here is my html code with the image and the input range

I tried to make an onchange on the input to change my image width but I didn't make it...

It's demotivating.

```
<div> 
<img id="image" className="carteImg" alt="Weiswampach Carte" src={map}/>
<input id="ranger" type="range" min="1" max="100" defaultValue="1"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const ScalingImage = () => {
  const [size, setSize] = useState(50);
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        id="ranger"
        type="range"
        min="1"
        max="100"
        value={size}
        onChange={e => {
          const { value } = e.target;
          setSize(parseInt(value, 10));
        }}
      />
      <div>
        <img
          id="image"
          className="carteImg"
          alt="Weiswampach Carte"
          src={img}
          style={{ width: `${size}%` }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Of course it can get more complicated depending on *how* you want to scale the image, but this is the basic premise.

Comment: Thanks ! Another question, if I have somme absolute div element on the image, how should i do to keep them at the right place ?